# Unable to make api calls from React Single Page app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-slingshot boilerplate and my component(which is making api call) is mounted on Root Component.  I am using BrowserRouter from navigation.

When I am making call from `/` path , api is working fine.
but When i am making from any other route, I am getting this error.

> Failed to load https://myapiserver.com/user/: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

I dont know what is the problem.

Comment: First check the logs of "myapiserver" for errors, to be sure. Then read about CORS. You should have to configure your server to accept requests from http://localhost:3000. Since you did not specify the server's language and framework, it is hard to help more specifically.

Comment: @JulienD ok, i will check

Answer (score 1):

What's your server?
This is a CORS thing, so you can server all this up from a web server, like http-server.

You have nothing to do here.Check [this doc from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

You need to add header to your web server's response. For example, see the following:

```
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />  
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />  
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
```

Change the above according to your syntax.